# Replace unknown XML value in bash

Tags: xml, linux, bash, command-line

I have a XML file, the format is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <input>
    <...>
        <file>1</file>
        ...
    </...>
    <network>
        <file>2</file>
        ...
    </network>
  </input>
  <output>
    <...>...</...>
    <file>...</file>
    ...
  </output>
</config>
```

I want to replace the value in < output >< file >...< /file >< /output > in command line, but I encountered some problems.

The first problem is there are multiple parameters named "file", so how to replace the value in the specific parameter < file > that I wanted?

The second problem is actually I don't know the value of the parameter "file", is there a method that I can replace the value without knowing it?

Comment: You can do this using xpath and xmlstarlet edit

Comment: @MévatlavéKraspek So is there a way to just use normal bash command, without installing xpath/xmlstarlet?

Comment: only xmlstarlet is to install. xpath is just the query language. Or you can write a python, perl, ruby script

Comment: "Is there a way?" is the wrong question.  There is a way to write an application one bit at a time, but you shouldn't.   Here, you shouldn't try to parse XML without an XML parser or XML tool such as XPath as @MévatlavéKraspek suggests:  Look into xmlstarlet or the XML processing facilities (***not*** regex) in the many scripting languages that can be called from bash.